# Form regular expression from byte array?

Tags: java, regex

How do I build a regular expression from a byte array?

For example, I have the array a:

```
byte[] a= {'A','T'} ;
```

I would like to match A to A or to G using the regex pattern of

```
   [AG]T
```

How can I use matcher?

Comment: Why do you need a `byte array` ?

Comment: From where did you get G ?

Comment: where did `G` come from

Comment: You want to build regular expression FROM byte array or FOR byte array ??

Comment: might be a possible solution http://blog.sarah-happy.ca/2013/01/java-regular-expression-on-byte-array.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
byte[] a= {'A','T'};
String aStr = new String(a);
String regex = "[AG]T";
if(aStr.matches(regex)){
     // Match
}else{
     // Not a match
}
```

You can try something like this.

Comment: Oh dear... The question clearly says "... regular expression from a byte array". This answer matches a regular expression _against_ a string _created from a byte array_. Though the OP accepted this answer you should have asked for clarification since the question is still unclear (to not just me). Thus (temporarily) downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

I came across a nice, clean solution at http://blog.sarah-happy.ca/2013/01/java-regular-expression-on-byte-array.html

The core is that you wrap the byte array in a helper class, and then apply standard classes.

```
package org.yi.happy.binary_regex;

public class ByteCharSequence implements CharSequence {

private final byte[] data;
private final int length;
private final int offset;

public ByteCharSequence(byte[] data) {
    this(data, 0, data.length);
}

public ByteCharSequence(byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
    this.data = data;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.length = length;
}

@Override
public int length() {
    return this.length;
}

@Override
public char charAt(int index) {
    return (char) (data[offset + index] & 0xff);
}

@Override
public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
    return new ByteCharSequence(data, offset + start, end - start);
}

}
```